# Having a runtime exception with Nutch 2.4 inject

Tags: java, nutch, accumulo

I am trying to inject the seeds into Nutch.

The command I used:

```
bin/nutch inject /root/project/nutch-old/runtime/local/conf/urls/
```

The result:

```
InjectorJob: starting at 2017-01-06 05:29:21

InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: /root/project/nutch-old/runtime/local/conf/urls

InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.accumulo.store.AccumuloStore as the Gora storage class.

InjectorJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=apache-nutch-2.4-SNAPSHOT.jar, jobid=job_local798287578_0001

at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:120)

at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:247)

at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:268)

at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:291)

at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)

at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:300)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to mention the seed URLs' file name as well which you may have kept under urls directory. Your command would be like `bin/nutch inject urls/seed.txt`
Please try out and let me know if it works.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Also it does say to use, just the dir path.

Comment: you have to have a text file with all the seed URLs. check for more detailed exception in runtime/local/logs/hadoop.log file?

Comment: There is a lot. But I think it's related to Nutch not being able to access Accumulo: java.io.IOException: org.apache.accumulo.core.client.AccumuloSecurityException: Error BAD_CREDENTIALS for user root - Username or Password is Invalid

Comment: I am still new to all of this.